# Can you make a voice call on android without user interaction

Tags: android, voice, callstack

I am trying to make an application that generate phone calls to create test data.
So I want the app to make a phone call to the same test phone number X times without the user to hit the call button. 
In my App I have been able to create a call but it requires the user to hit the call button

I am using the following command which is suppose to dial once the dialer is up 
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+PhoneNumber)));

I have the following definitions in the manifest file

I am using Android 2.2.1 OS on a Samsung Fascinate

Comment: So it possible if I root my phone? Was what I did for code correct if it were Rooted?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not possible without running on a rooted phone. This is to protect the user. I'd imagine an application could rack-up a hefty phone bill to shady numbers unbeknownst to the user if that were possible.

Comment: So it possible if I root my phone?  Was what I did for code correct if it were Rooted?